# Bootstrap 3.0 Glyphicons not working in IE and FF

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I've got this site where I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.2
The issue is that in Chrome, the glyphicons are showing perfectly but Both in IE and FF they don't, in FF the icons are shown as a small box with numbers in, and in the FF console I get this

```
[11:31:54.537] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://url.com.com/templates/a_template/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 

[11:31:54.691] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://url.com/templates/a_template/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 

[11:31:54.691] downloadable font: no supported format found (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:4)
source: (end of source list)
```

and in IE (any version I've tried so far) I get no icons at all and the console shows this

```
CSS3117: A error occurred in a request to the origin of @ font-face. There is limited access to the resource.
glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot

CSS3117: A error occurred in a request to the origin of @ font-face. There is limited access to the resource.
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

CSS3117: A error occurred in a request to the origin of @ font-face. There is limited access to the resource.
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

I've tried every solution I've been cable of finding here and on google but with little  luck.

In my template I include these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $template_path; ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $template_path; ?>/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How do I get the icons to show in IE and FF?

Comment: Looks like there are either bad permissions on the font files, or you are trying to pull them from a different domain and its causing issues.  Try going to those URLs that FF is giving errors on and see if you can access the file.

Comment: I've tried with permissions set to 777 (using ubuntu) and they are on the same domain / server, so I have no idea why it's tossing that up. and if I try to access them through the URL given my Firefox they DL just fine

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that the only icon that shows both in IE and FF is the envelope icon for some reason.

Comment: I would say this thread is off-topic because the problem/solution are very localized to this environment. I don't believe it's of general interest to either users debugging glyphicons or looking for apache permissions problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, a previous manager of the site had added a .htaccess file to the template folder which didn't add www. before the load, so the entire site loaded with www. while the template folder loaded without www. changed this to load with www. and it fixed everything :)